# assignment of string using strcpy and equal operator

Tags: c, pointers, strcpy

What is difference between the following code?

1.

```
char *p;
strcpy(p,"String");
```

2.

```
char *p;
p = "String";
```

The pointer points to the same string, but is there any difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for the first operation to work, `p` must point to a writable block of memory at least 7 bytes in size. The second operation does not require it.

After the first operation the string remains writable: you can do this on the first string, but not the second:

```
*p= 's'; // Make the value all lowercase
```

The second pointer assignment points `p` to a memory of a string literal; writing to that memory is undefined behavior.

Comment: @MitchWheat You're right :)

Comment: plus yours is the better answer.

Comment: Does this apply if you say p = ""? Is the empty string considered a string literal in read-only memory?

Comment: @rasen58 Yes, `""` is a string literal in read-only memory. It occupies one byte, i.e. `'\0'`. Writing to it is UB.

Answer (score 1):

`(1)` is a memory scribble and possibly a runtime error.

You cannot copy into memory you don't own (haven't allocated in some way).

Answer (score 1):

In the first point you say you want to copy the string to the memblock p is pointing to

(so you have to make sure, there is enough space where the string can be copied to)

In the second case you just make p pointing to the read only address of "String".

`p -> [S][t][r][i][n][g][0]`

But you should get compiler warnings as far you don't declare p as `p const *`

Comment: hence in first String is copied to another location and then address is assigned to pointer.
But in second direct address of String is assigned to p.